# Full date Validation in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, datetime

I would like to make a validation for date. the date has many formats:
European and American styles. Also, number, shortcut or even the month full name.

I used `Date.parse()` but it's not accurate and it has many issues. For example: it doesn't pay attention to the leap year. Also, I added "35/02/2008" without giving me any exception.

I tried regular expression but all of what I found has an issue.
None of them cover the whole possibilities.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Joda Time library: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Input_and_Output

For example, you can create a DateTimeFormatter, and parse some text using it:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(strInputDateTime);
```

The library allows for constructing complex date time patterns and it has knowledge of leap years etc.

Comment: please comment recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Date validation does not make sense unless you are validating against a specific date format, or (carefully chosen) set of formats.  To illustrate, consider this:

```
    23/11/77
```

Is that a valid date?  It depends!

- If you are validating against "dd/MM/YY", then yes it is valid.
- If you are validating against "MM/dd/YY", then no it isn't.
- If you are validating against "dd/MM/YYYY", then it is valid but it doesn't mean what you think it means.

In short validating "any date" irrespective of format make no sense.  The above date *could be* either valid or invalid, and can mean different things.

The fact that people "know" what these dates mean is worrying.  In fact, when most people see a date, they interpret according to their own cultural norms ... without realizing that most dates are *ambiguous* if the format is not specified / agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (or aren't allowed) to use third-party libraries and prefer having manual control over validations, split the string using "/" as separators, then making conditions for all needed cases:

```
String pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String strDate = df.format(date);
String[] arrDate = strDate.split("/");

int year = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[1]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[2]);

if (month == 2 && day > 28) {
    System.out.println("February has 28 days!");
}
// etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 then you dont need joda. There is an in-build API LocalDateTime similarly for UTC also there is an API.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that the input may come with different format as soon as my app is an analysis tool.
If I wanna do it manually by splitting the date, I have to create a full class in order to check all the possibilities in all different formats.
There's no full regular expression for this issue. How come?